# PySide - QSortFilterProxyModel and QListView - indexWidget pointer get deleted when filtering

Tags: filtering, pyside, qwidget, qlistview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've a problem with a custom `QListView` I'm trying to make, here the problem:

I'm using `QListView` to show a list of `QWidget` by using `QListView.setIndexWidget(index,widget)`.

This is working pretty fine, but now I want to filter the items model by using `QSortFilterProxyModel()`
with `.setFilterWildcard()`

It is not working very well because the second time the model is filtered
I got error like this :

`RuntimeError: Internal C++ object (PySide.QtGui.QLabel) already deleted.`

Without using `filtering` and `QSortFilterProxyModel` everything works fine, but it seems I'm missing
something with the filtering operation, the `indexWidget()` is deleted when using filtering :(

here a sample code where you can reproduce the bug, when list view is shown, hit 1,2 or 3 keyboard
key to activate filtering ( Backspace to set filtering empty to show all items )

Here the sample code to reproduce the problem:

```py
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore


_DEFAULT_ITEM_SIZE = QtCore.QSize(100, 85)
_USER_ROLE = QtGui.QStandardItem.UserType + 1

class CustomItemWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomItemWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        #self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        # Default brush and pen
        bg_brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("#8C8C8C"))
        pen = QtCore.Qt.NoPen

        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(bg_brush)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 12, 12)
        painter.restore()

    def setData(self, role, value):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            self.label.setText(value)



class CustomItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomItem, self).__init__()

        self.number = None
        self.item_widget = CustomItemWidget()
        self.setSelectable(True)

    def type(self):
        return _USER_ROLE

    def data(self, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = "DATA %s" % str(self.number)
            self.item_widget.setData(role, value)

            return value

        if role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            return _DEFAULT_ITEM_SIZE

        return QtGui.QStandardItem.data(self, role)



class CustomItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent=parent)


class CustomItemModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomItemModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | \
            QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | \
            QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | \
            QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled


class CustomItemFilterProxyModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomItemFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.setFilterKeyColumn(0)


class CustomView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomView, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setIconSize(_DEFAULT_ITEM_SIZE)
        self.setMovement(QtGui.QListView.Static)
        self.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.setFlow(QtGui.QListView.LeftToRight)
        self.setResizeMode(QtGui.QListView.Adjust)

        self.data_model = CustomItemModel(self)
        self.proxy_model = CustomItemFilterProxyModel(self)

        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.data_model)
        self.setModel(self.proxy_model)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_1:
            self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard("*1*")
            print self.proxy_model.filterRegExp()
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_2:
            self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard("*2*")
            print self.proxy_model.filterRegExp()
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_3:
            self.proxy_model.setFilterWildcard("*3*")
            print self.proxy_model.filterRegExp()
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backspace:
            self.proxy_model.setFilterFixedString("")
            print self.proxy_model.filterRegExp()
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Plus:
            self.addNewItem()

        QtGui.QListView.keyPressEvent(self, event)

    def addNewItem(self):
        item = CustomItem()
        item.number = self.data_model.rowCount()

        self.addItem(item)

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.data_model.appendRow(item)
        proxy_index = self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(item.index())

        self.setIndexWidget(proxy_index, item.item_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    qapplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    window = QtGui.QDialog()
    window.setLayout(layout)

    view = CustomView(window)
    view.resize(800, 600)

    layout.addWidget(view)

    for i in range(0, 10):
        item = CustomItem()
        item.number = i
        view.addItem(item)


    window.show()

    sys.exit(qapplication.exec_())
```

or sample code here:

https://gist.github.com/66e29df303d1f1825a53

Can someone please help me on this? is this a known bug ? or I'm doing it completely wrong :P

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've forgot to mention I've tested this with `PySide 1.2.1` on Linux with `Python 2.7.5`

Comment: Also found same related unanswered question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/17854877/3884275

Comment: For me code runs fine. (PySide 1.2.2, Python 3.3 64 Bit, Win 7 64 Bit)

Comment: @Trilarion Thanks for testing it ! I will try to test it with PySide 1.2.2, maybe something has been fixed in this version...

Comment: Well I've also tested with `PySide 1.2.2`, `Python 2.7.5`, on `MacOsx Maverick`, and I got the same probleme ... :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as I struggled with a similar problem for quite a while, here the solution I found and a possible explanation:

Instead of caching the custom widget on the model item, I cached the data needed to create the widget. In my case, I wanted to use a custom label with html in order to be able to format parts of text in different colour. Hence, I cached the html string on the item.

Then, in the `initStyleOption` method of the item delegate, I recreated the widget if it didn't yet exist or had disappeared after filtering:

```
  label = self.parent().indexWidget(modelIndex)
  if not label:
    label = CustomLabel(item.html)
    self.parent().setIndexWidget(modelIndex, label)
```

The reason why filtering deletes the widget cached on the item is as follows, I believe: the widget can "exist" only in one place. When it is put as indexWidget, it "exists" on a row in the view, not in an item of the model any more. As filtering removes rows from view, widgets on those rows get deleted. - A poor explanation, but I've often got similar surprises when manipulating html elements with JavaScript if I've forgotten to clone the element.